# Fastest way to do data type conversion using csv.DictReader in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, type-conversion

I'm working with a CSV file in python, which will have ~100,000 rows when in use. Each row has a set of dimensions (as strings) and a single metric (float).

As csv.DictReader or csv.reader return values as string only, I'm currently iterating over all rows and converting the one numeric value to a float.

```
for i in csvDict:
    i[col] = float(i[col])
```

Is there a better way that anyone could suggest to do this? I've been playing around with various combinations of map, izip, itertools and have searched extensively for some samples of doing it more efficiently, but unfortunately haven't had much success.

In case it helps:
I'm doing this on appengine. I *believe* that what I'm doing may be resulting in me hitting  this error: 
Exceeded soft process size limit with 267.789 MB after servicing 11 requests total - I only get it when the CSV is quite large.

**Edit: My Goal**
I'm parsing this CSV so that I can use it as a [data source for the Google Visualizations API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/implementing_data_source.html). The final data set will be loaded in to a gviz DataTable for querying. Type must be specified during the construction of this table. My problem could also be solved if anyone knew of a good gviz csv->datatable converter in python!

**Edit2: My Code**

I believe that my issue has to do with the way I attempt to fixCsvTypes(). Also, data_table.LoadData() expects an iterable object.

```
class GvizFromCsv(object):
  """Convert CSV to Gviz ready objects."""

  def __init__(self, csvFile, dateTimeFormat=None):
    self.fileObj = StringIO.StringIO(csvFile)
    self.csvDict = list(csv.DictReader(self.fileObj))
    self.dateTimeFormat = dateTimeFormat
    self.headers = {}
    self.ParseHeaders()
    self.fixCsvTypes()

  def IsNumber(self, st):
    try:
        float(st)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

  def IsDate(self, st):
    try:
      datetime.datetime.strptime(st, self.dateTimeFormat)
    except ValueError:
      return False

  def ParseHeaders(self):
    """Attempts to figure out header types for gviz, based on first row"""
    for k, v in self.csvDict[0].items():
      if self.IsNumber(v):
        self.headers[k] = 'number'
      elif self.dateTimeFormat and self.IsDate(v):
        self.headers[k] = 'date'
      else:
        self.headers[k] = 'string'

  def fixCsvTypes(self):
    """Only fixes numbers."""
    update_to_numbers = []
    for k,v in self.headers.items():
      if v == 'number':
        update_to_numbers.append(k)
    for i in self.csvDict:
      for col in update_to_numbers:
        i[col] = float(i[col])

  def CreateDataTable(self):
    """creates a gviz data table"""
    data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(self.headers)
    data_table.LoadData(self.csvDict)
    return data_table
```

Comment: What do you do with this data? Process line after line or put them into some data structure?

Comment: I intend on doing no other line processing beyond fixing types. The results will be used as the data to construct a gviz DataTable - I've now added this to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had first exploited the CSV file with a regex, but since the data in the file is very strictly arranged in each row, we can simply use the **split()** function

```
import gviz_api

scheme = [('col1','string','SURNAME'),('col2','number','ONE'),('col3','number','TWO')]
data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(scheme)

#  --- lines in surnames.csv are : --- 
#  surname,percent,cumulative percent,rank\n
#  SMITH,1.006,1.006,1,\n
#  JOHNSON,0.810,1.816,2,\n
#  WILLIAMS,0.699,2.515,3,\n

with open('surnames.csv') as f:

    def transf(surname,x,y):
        return (surname,float(x),float(y))

    f.readline()
    # to skip the first line surname,percent,cumulative percent,rank\n

    data_table.LoadData( transf(*line.split(',')[0:3]) for line in f )
    # to populate the data table by iterating in the CSV file
```

Or without a function to be defined:

```
import gviz_api

scheme = [('col1','string','SURNAME'),('col2','number','ONE'),('col3','number','TWO')]
data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(scheme)

#  --- lines in surnames.csv are : --- 
#  surname,percent,cumulative percent,rank\n
#  SMITH,1.006,1.006,1,\n
#  JOHNSON,0.810,1.816,2,\n
#  WILLIAMS,0.699,2.515,3,\n

with open('surnames.csv') as f:

    f.readline()
    # to skip the first line surname,percent,cumulative percent,rank\n

    datdata_table.LoadData( [el if n==0 else float(el) for n,el in enumerate(line.split(',')[0:3])] for line in f )    
    # to populate the data table by iterating in the CSV file
```

At one moment, I believed I was obliged to populate the data table with one row at a time because I was using a regex and that needed to obtain the matches' groups before floating the numbers' strings. With **split()** all can be done in one instruction with **LoadData()**

.

Hence, your code can be shortened. By the way, I don't see why it should continue to define a class. Instead, a function seems enough for me:

```
def GvizFromCsv(filename):
  """ creates a gviz data table from a CSV file """

  data_table = gviz_api.DataTable([('col1','string','SURNAME'),
                                   ('col2','number','ONE'    ),
                                   ('col3','number','TWO'    ) ])

  #  --- with such a table schema , lines in the file must be like that: ---  
  #  blah, number, number, ...anything else...\n 
  #  SMITH,1.006,1.006, ...anything else...\n 
  #  JOHNSON,0.810,1.816, ...anything else...\n 
  #  WILLIAMS,0.699,2.515, ...anything else...\n

  with open(filename) as f:
    data_table.LoadData( [el if n==0 else float(el) for n,el in enumerate(line.split(',')[0:3])]
                         for line in f )
  return data_table
```

.

Now you must examine if the way in which the CSV data is read from another API can be inserted in this code to keep the iterating principle to populate the data table.

Comment: Thank you! For the sake of completion I've included both solutions on this pad: http://piratepad.net/fJfKE2Juyl The only minor consideration I needed to take with your code was that column type identification needs to be handled automatically (ideally, this code should be able to interpret any csv without the user instructing it), assuming the user doesn't know it already. Also - I did some basic time comparisons - both the class and your function took ~6 seconds over 80,000 rows, with your winning out by a marginal amount over 20 runs.

Comment: @oli float('45.89\n') doesn't give an error but datetime.datetime.strptime('2014 4 28\n','%Y %m %d') does. So you should write [getConvType(el.strip('\n'))[0] for el in f.next()] instead of [getConvType(el)[0] for el in f.next()], and the same for [getConvType(el)[1] for el in f.next()] , in case there is a datetime string in the last position of each line.

Comment: @oli But in fact, it would be better to write [el for el in f.readline()[0:-1].split(',')] and to write [getConvType(el)[1] for el in f.next()[0:-1].split(',')] and to write [getConvType(el)[0] for el in line[0:-1].split(',')] . The point is to add [0:-1] . It will always work if the Universal Neawline Support is enabled, which is the default.

Comment: @oli I am improving the code on some points, but I met a problem that I don't understand. You will have to watch to read when I will have been able and the time to debug.

Answer (score 1):

First, you *don't need* any conversion if you need to *only* visualize these data: gviz can handle JSON (text-based, you know) or CSV (you already have it, no parsing required!). You can put the file in question on any reasonable web server and allow it to be accessed with fancy GET requests gviz issues, basically by ignoring the parameters.

But let's assume you need processing. It looks like you not only read the CSV file but also try to store it entirely in RAM. This may be impractical: you will hit RAM limit sooner and sooner as you add more processing. Process data one line at a time (or a reasonable number of lines if you apply window filters, etc) and put processed rows to the data store, not to any list, etc. Equally, when serving data via a GET request, read / process a row, write it to the response, and don't put it into any list or whatnot.

I see no problem with the conversion technique, as long as you use `i` reasonably later in code and don't memorize all `i`s as you go.

Comment: Really helpful response, thanks a huge amount. Some notes: 1) The only reason I'm doing all of this is because I thought I needed to process the CSV before sending it to gviz. I did not think gviz handled CSV files as a DS. I'm currently trying to do: csv->DataTable.toJsonResponse(). From what you said, I may not need to do that at all - going to have a play now. I'm restricted in that the CSV _must_ come in through python, but I'd happy just shove it out as a gviz datasource. 2) If I use CSV as the datasource, and perform queries on top of that, will it figure out the types (for summing etc)?

Comment: I don't know if I can just use the CSV with gviz - http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/browse_thread/thread/9d1d941e0f0b32ed could you let me know if you know differently?

Comment: Following the link you posted: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/implementing_data_source.html#csvdatatable

Comment: In the linked passage "The Java and Python open source libraries provide a method to convert a DataTable to a CSV string." oli wants to do the contrary: "My Goal I'm parsing this CSV so that I can use it as a data source for the Google Visualizations API."

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct things:
"data source" and "data table".

"data source" is the name of the formatted data that is delivered by the Google Visualization API server as a Visualization web service:

```
This page describes how you can implement a data source to feed data
to visualizations built on the Google Visualization API. 

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/implementing_data_source.html
```

The name "data source" includes the notion of "wire protocol":

```
In response [to a request], the data source returns properly formatted data 
that the visualization can use to render the graphic on the page. 
This request-response protocol is known as the Google Visualization API wire protocol,

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/implementing_data_source_overview.html
```

To implement the "data source", there are two possibilities:

```
• Use one of the data source libraries listed in the Data Sources and Tools Gallery. 
All the data source libraries listed on that page implement the wire protocol.

• Write your own data source from scratch, 

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/implementing_data_source_overview.html
```

From the following:

```
• ... Data Sources and Tools Gallery : (....) You therefore need write only the
code needed to make your data available to the library in the form of a data table. 

• Write your own data source from scratch, as described in the
Writing your own Data Source
```

I understand that from scratch, we need to implement ourselves the wire protocol + the creation of a "data table", while with a data source library, we just have to create the "data table".

---

There are pages on the creation of a "data source"

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/implementing_data_source_overview.html

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/gviz_api_lib.html

In my opinion, the example at the address http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/browse_thread/thread/9d1d941e0f0b32ed is about the creation of a "data source" and the answer made there is dubious. But that's not very clear to me.

---

But these pages and subject are not the interesting ones for you, who wants, in fact, if I understand well, to know how to prepare the data, known as "data table", to be served through the "data source" , but not the construction of the "data source".

```
3.Prepare your data. You'll need to prepare the data to visualize; 
this means either specifying the data yourself in code, 
or querying a remote site for data.

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/using_overview.html#keycomponents

A visualization stores the data that it visualizes as two-dimensional data table with 
rows and columns.
Cells are referenced by (row, column) where row is a zero-based row number, and column
is either a zero-based column index or a unique ID that you can specify. 

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/using_overview.html#preparedata
```

So, the preparation of the "data table" is the key point.

Here it is:

```
There are two ways to create/populate your visualization's data table:

•Query a data provider. A data provider is another site that returns
a populated DataTable in response to a request from your code. 
Some data providers also accept SQL-like query strings to sort or 
filter the data. See Data Queries for more information and an example
of a query.

•Create and populate your own DataTable by hand. You can populate your
DataTable in code on your page. The simplest way to do this is to create
a DataTable object without any data and populate it by calling addRows()
on it. You can also pass a JavaScript literal representation of the data
table into the DataTable constructor, but this is more complex and is
covered on the reference page.

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/using_overview.html#preparedata
```

Further information is found here:

```
2. Describe your table schema
The table schema is specified by the table_description parameter
passed into the constructor. You cannot change it later. 
The schema describes all the columns in the table: the data type of
each column, the ID, and an optional label.

Each column is described by a tuple: (ID [,data_type [,label [,custom_properties]]]). 



The table schema is a collection of column descriptor tuples. 
Every list member, dictionary key or dictionary value must be either 
another collection or a descriptor tuple. You can use any combination 
of dictionaries or lists, but every key, value, or member must
eventually evaluate to a descriptor tuple. Here are some examples.

•List of columns: [('a', 'number'), ('b', 'string')]
•Dictionary of lists: {('a', 'number'): [('b', 'number'), ('c', 'string')]}
•Dictionary of dictionaries: {('a', 'number'): {'b': 'number', 'c': 'string'}}
•And so on, with any level of nesting.


3. Populate your data
To add data to the table, build a structure of data elements in the
exact same structure as the table schema. So, for example, if your
schema is a list, the data must be a list: 

•schema: [("color", "string"), ("shape", "string")] 
•data: [["blue", "square"], ["red", "circle"]] 
If the schema is a dictionary, the data must be a dictionary:

•schema: {("rowname", "string"): [("color", "string"), ("shape", "string")] }
•data: {"row1": ["blue", "square"], "row2": ["red", "circle"]}

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/gviz_api_lib.html#populatedata
```

Finally, i would say that for your problem, you have to define a "table schema" and to process your CSV file in order to obtain `a structure of data elements in the exact same structure as the table schema.`

Definition of the type of data in a column is done in the "table schema" 's definition. If populating the "data table" must be done with data having the right type (not string, I want to say) I will help you to write the code for the extraction of data from the CSV, it's simple to do.

For the moment, I hope all this is right and will help

Comment: Eyquem, really appreciate you taking the time to respond. I've included my code in the post; it intends to convert a CSV to a DataTable object in python. Once the data is in the right format, the actual conversion to DataTable will be taken care of by the gviz_api (handled in CreateDataTable()).I intend on exposing it as a data source. I believe the issue, as @9000 mentioned, is with fixCsvTypes() which attempts to loop through all entries and convert appropriate columns to numbers (or, in the future datetimes etc), and saving them along the way. Perhaps self.csvDict ends up being too large?

Comment: @oli Thank you. Maybe there was too much explanation about points you already knew. But it allowed me to learn the subject! I've just read your code. "Also, data_table.LoadData() expects an iterable object." Perfect. This will permit to iterate into self.csvDict to populate the DataTable. But something lacks to me: where's the csvFile at the moment it will be given to the GvizFromCsv instance? I don't think it is needed to process the file with StringIO.StringIO. This latter is used to read strings as files; but you already have a file. I don't undesrtand the motivation of introducing StringIO

Comment: @Eyquem hopefully we can all get something from this :). Points: 1)The CSV string actually comes from another API in the format: "Col1,Col2,Col3\nHi,There,123,". For some reason, StringIO.StringIO was the only way that I could get this to parse correctly (otherwise it would split my CSV string at each character, not comma). 2) It is useful that csv.Dict can populate the DataTable, but my problem is that I need to convert an entry in each row of csv.Dict from string to float before doing so. I'm investigating gviz_api.AppendData (append rows one at a time), which may help here.

Comment: @oli "my problem is that I need to convert an entry in each row of csv.Dict from string to float before doing so" Yes I understood that. But no, I don't think it must be done following the way you entered in. That's why I gather information and knowledge about the subject to do it with my idea. You gave me "Col1,Col2,Col3\nHi,There,123," that's good to continue. I've just succeeded to download and unzip the 'google-visualization-python' repertory. I'll propose you some modification in a moment.

Comment: @oli Could you give me the value of csvDict[0] . I see that ParseHeaders() use this value to return self.headers filled with the table schema, which is passed to gviz_api.DataTable() to instantiate a DataTable

Comment: @oli Yeeees : print gviz_api.DataTable.SingleValueToJS(5.45,'number') prints 5.45 . So a float is accepted . I wished to verify this point.

Comment: @eyquem I think I may have solved the memory issue by appending each row as I iterate through csv.Dict, instead of saving it in a list then using gviz_api.LoadData(). My most recent code is here: http://piratepad.net/fJfKE2Juyl . I'm using a test data set: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/data/surnames.csv . csvDict[0] is now csv.next() and gives: {'cumulative percent': '1.006', 'percent': '1.006', 'surname': 'SMITH', 'rank': '1'} . If you can, take a look and see what you think!

Comment: @oli "instead of saving it in a list " Me too. But I am finishing to write a code to iterate directly in the CSV file , without having to create a csvDict. I am searching the instruction by which we can populate the DataTable one row at a time

Comment: I believe that it is gviz_api.AppendData(). See fixRowTypesAndAppendToDataTable() here: http://piratepad.net/fJfKE2Juyl

Comment: @oli Yes I found it : AppenData . I have my solution. I take a time to exploit your last comments

Comment: @oli I did essays with a file composed of lines based on the ""Col1,Col2,Col3\nHi,There,123," shape. But now I've downloaded the surnames.txt file, I see the lines in it are "SMITH,1.006,1.006,1" "JOHNSON,0.810,1.816,2" "WILLIAMS,0.699,2.515,3" There are not only one number but 3 in each line. What number's strings do you want to transform into float to construct the data table ?